# \pgfplotstableread and subfiles

Tags: tikz-pgf, include, subfiles

Is there a way to use a folder structure with `subfiles` and `\pgfplotstableread`?

I have the following structure:

```
main.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\begin{document}
\subfile{chapters/chapter1.tex}
\end{document}
```

and the second file:

```
chapter1.tex
\documentclass[../main.tex]{subfiles} 
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotstableread{<PATH>}\loadedtable
   ...some plot
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Now `<PATH>` can either be set so that `main.tex` works or `chapter1.tex` but not both because the are in different directories. Is there a way to use this feature without giving up folder structures?

Comment: So the main problem is to go up in the folder tree and enter another subfolder for the data right? Does it have to be `subfiles` solution?

Comment: The main problem is to be aware whether the subfile is compiled by itself or as an include for the main file. The `<PATH>` has to be different for both alternatives.

Comment: Maybe then you should nest the tikzpicture too as a fixed path so it doesn't matter whether main or chapter is called it. Otherwise you need to check each time who is pulling the strings.

Comment: can you expand on that. Do you mean that I should move the file or can I do something with tikz there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the `standalone` package is not the perfect solution, I found a better way with `subfiles`

```
main.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\fromRoot}[1]{./#1}%will not be read by subfiles
\subfile{chapters/chapter1.tex}
\end{document}
```

and the second file:

```
chapter1.tex
\documentclass[../main.tex]{subfiles}

\makeatletter
\@ifundefined{fromRoot}{\newcommand{\fromRoot}[1]{../#1}}{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotstableread{\fromRoot{<PATH>}}\loadedtable
   ...some plot
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Now everthing works as intended.

Answer (score 2):

I solved that problem by switching to `standalone` because it has the macro `\onlyifstandalone`. The following setup works:

```
main.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\newcommand{\fromRoot}[1]{./#1}
\begin{document}
\subfile{chapters/chapter1.tex}
\end{document}
```

and the second file:

```
chapter1.tex
\documentclass{subfiles}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\onlyifstandalone{\newcommand{\fromRoot}[1]{../../#1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotstableread{\fromRoot{<PATH>}}\loadedtable
   ...some plot
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Now `<PATH>` is the relative path from the root directory of the project.

Answer (score 1):

I knew this is an ancient question but i have an other convinient way based on answer of OP so that we don't have to retype the same command definition in every subfiles using pgfplotstable.

Supposing the folder structure like this :

```
root
--main.tex
++sections
  --subfile.tex
++res
  --table.csv
```

In `main.tex`

```latex
\newcommand{\getResources}[1]{../res/#1}%relative to `sections` folder

\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\getResources}[1]{./res/#1}%relative to root folder
\end{document}
```

In `subfile.tex`, call your csv file with `getResources`

```latex
\pgfplotstabletypeset[...]{\getResources{table.csv}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Reading the documentation of subfiles I tried the command `\subfix{...}` which did the job for me, i.e.

```
chapter1.tex
\documentclass[../main.tex]{subfiles} 
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotstableread{\subfix{<PATH>}}\loadedtable
   ...some plot
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```