# Combining different projects into one (papers into PhD Thesis)

Tags: input, include, paths

My question is similar to this [one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4889/input-only-part-of-a-file), but I have a problem with relative paths when including files.

Assume I have three projects which all start with

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[]{}
...
\usepackage[]{}
\begin{document}
...
\input{parts/chapter1}
...
\includegraphics{graphics/figure1.eps}
...
\end{document}
```

All these projects include own relative paths to other resources, e.g. graphics and chapters.

My goal is to build a new file that will contain all three including everything between `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`, such that I can work on my three small projects and easily compile them into my PhD Thesis.

I could get it working with package [catchfilebetweentags](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/catchfilebetweentags/), but with full paths only. I also found another package [import](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4602/how-to-make-the-main-file-recognize-relative-paths-used-in-the-imported-files) that helps to recognize relative paths. But I do not know how to combine these two packages. Can one help?

A simple example:

main.tex

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{import}
\begin{document}
1.Hello World
\subimport{test/}{inputFile.tex}
\end{document}
```

test/inputFile.tex

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\begin{document}
2.Hello World\\
\input{inputFile2.tex}
\end{document}
```

test/inputFile2.tex

```
3.Hello World
```

It would work if I commented `\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}`, `\begin{document}`, `\end{document}` in inputFile.tex. But then I cannot compile inputFile.tex independently.

Comment: Do you need to compile your subprojects independently? If not, set up a general file like thesis.tex which has a proper preamble and loads all the packages you need. Then use `input` after the `begin{document}` command to load the subprojects. These files should then only contain the text (and markup needed for it). You can still compile only one subproject by commenting out the other project files.

Comment: I solved that problem for my Master thesis and posted the results here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/124228/pgfplotstableread-and-subfiles

Comment: @Chris the point is that I'm working with only subprojets and do compile them independently.

Comment: @papabravo there are other people working on subprojects with me and I cannot really change their structure such that they notice it.

Comment: I think without changing something in the subfiles this task is close to impossible. The packages you are suggesting will not take care of package or makro clashes between subfiles and main file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11311/how-to-include-a-document-into-another-document See especially [Martin's answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/11318/119).

Comment: @cherep, so other people are working on your PhD thesis? :o

Answer (score 1):

I got it working with `import` package and linux terminal command `sed` that creates inputFileDis.tex with the text between `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}` from inputFile.tex:

```
sed -n -e '0,/^\\begin{document}$/d' -e '/^\\end{document}/,$d' -e p test/inputFile.tex > test/inputFileDis.tex
```

which I need to run every time before I compile main.tex.

Then main.tex

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{import}
\begin{document}
1.Hello World
\subimport{test/}{inputFileDis.tex}
\end{document}
```

test/inputFile.tex

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\begin{document}
2.Hello World\\
\input{inputFile2.tex}
\end{document}
```

test/inputFileDis.tex

```
2.Hello World\\
\input{inputFile2.tex}
```

test/inputFile2.tex

```
3.Hello World
```

Does anyone have better solution in mind?

Comment: Perhaps the combine package? http://www.ctan.org/pkg/combine