# tikz externalize and pgfmath error

Tags: pgfplots, tikz-external, pgfmath

Using `external` and `\pgfmathdeclarefunction` at the same time results in

```
! Illegal parameter number in definition of \pgfmathfloat@expression.
! Package PGF Math Error: Could not parse input '' as a floating point number, sorry. The unreadable part was near ''. (in '##1').
```

This is an MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}\usetikzlibrary{external}
\begin{document}
\tikzexternalize
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{f}{1}{\pgfmathparse{#1}}
\begin{axis}
\addplot {f(x)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

What causes these problems and how can I solve them?

Comment: Move `\tikzexternalize` in the preamble.

Comment: That actually helps. Is it possible to keep the it in the document body? I need that for my project structure.

Comment: I'm afraid, I think you cannot. But, if you can elaborate more your needs, you will have greater chances to receive a good answer.

Comment: @papabravo: No, that's not possible. From the manual: "This command activates the externalization. It installs commands to replace every TikZ-picture. It
needs to be called before `\begin{document}` because it may need to install its separate shipout routine."

Comment: I have this setup with subfiles: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/124228/pgfplotstableread-and-subfiles and I want it to work with `externalize` but that is probably a different question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved in the comments.